# Is there a way to instantiate an object with a file having a nested class?

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to do pop() and push() in the following code, but the methods are not being recognized. I am thinking that it has to do with the declaring of the object val (MyStack.StackNode val = new MyStack.StackNode(4);).  According to some sources, when there is a nested class, the outer class is named first followed by the inner class.

Update: Error message I am getting is the following,

```
    java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable next
  location: variable node of type Practice<java.lang.Integer>
```

//

```
    import java.util.EmptyStackException;


public class Practice<T> {

    private static class StackNode<T> {
        private T data;
        private StackNode<T> next;

        public StackNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private StackNode<T> top;

    public T pop(int i) {
        if (top == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        T item = top.data;
        top = top.next;
        return item;
    }

    public void push(T item) {
        StackNode<T> t = new StackNode<T>(item);
        t.next = top;
        top = t;
    }

    public T peek() {
        if (top == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        return top.data;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Practice<Integer> val = new Practice<Integer>();

        val.push(5);
        val.push(7);
        val.pop(5);

        for (Practice<Integer> node = val; node != null; node = node.next) {
            System.out.println(node.val);
        }

    }
}
```

///

```
Expected output:

4
7
```

Comment: 1) Your expected output doesn't match your input data 2) your code contains typos and/or code that doesn't compile. Rey fix that first. Also please clarify what error you are getting and not understanding.

Comment: Your declaring your variable as a StackNode in main, the methods you're calling exist on MyStack not StackNode. Change your type to MyStack. You shouldn't be able to manipulate your stack outside of the provided methods you give for MyStack.

Comment: `Practice` doesn't have a `next` field. Maybe you meant `val.top.next`? And I'm not sure what `node.val` is supposed to refer to. Maybe `data`? You need to think through your code more carefully. If you can't explain it, word by word, to a [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/), your computer probably can't understand it.

Comment: I had to change the class to Practice since that was what the file name was.  Practice = MyStack.